# GCC looks for .o file

Tags: gcc, makefile

Consider the following Makefile

```
include ../../common/make.config
CC = gcc
CC_FLAGS = -g -fopenmp -O2
NVCC = $(CUDA_DIR)/bin/nvcc
NVCC_FLAGS = -I$(CUDA_DIR)/include

# 'make dbg=1' enables NVCC debugging
ifeq ($(dbg),1)
        NVCC_FLAGS += -g -O0
else
        NVCC_FLAGS += -O2
endif

# 'make emu=1' compiles the CUDA kernels for emulation
ifeq ($(emu),1)
        NVCC_FLAGS += -deviceemu
endif


kmeans: cluster.o getopt.o kmeans.o kmeans_clustering.o kmeans_cuda.o rmse.o
        $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) cluster.o getopt.o kmeans.o kmeans_clustering.o kmeans_cuda.o rmse.o -o kmeans -L$(CUDA_LIB_DIR) -lcuda -lcudart -lm

%.o: %.[ch]
        $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $< -c

kmeans_cuda.o: kmeans_cuda.cu
        $(NVCC) $(NVCC_FLAGS) -c kmeans_cuda.cu

clean:
        rm -f *.o *~ kmeans kmeans_cuda.linkinfo
```

When I run `make`, I get this error

```
$ make
gcc -g -fopenmp -O2  kmeans.h -c
gcc -g -fopenmp -O2  cluster.o getopt.o kmeans.o kmeans_clustering.o kmeans_cuda.o rmse.o -o kmeans -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lm
gcc: error: kmeans.o: No such file or directory
```

The files are

```
$ ls
cluster.c  getopt.c  getopt.o  kmeans_clustering.c  kmeans_cuda.cu         kmeans_cuda.o  kmeans.h.gch  Makefile_nvidia  rmse.c  run
cluster.o  getopt.h  kmeans.c  kmeans_clustering.o  kmeans_cuda_kernel.cu  kmeans.h       Makefile      README           rmse.o  unistd.h
```

Although there is `kmeans.c`, I wonder why there is no `kmeans.o` and therefore, it can not link the object files in the next step.

Any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the rule...

```
%.o: %.[ch]
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $< -c
```

For some reason it appears that for the stem `kmeans` `%.[ch]` is being expanded as `kmeans.h kmeans.c` so that rule, when expanded, becomes...

```
kmeans.o: kmeans.h kmeans.c
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $< -c
```

The builtin variable `$<` refers to the first prerequisite which in this case is `kmeans.h`, hence you see the compilation command...

```
gcc -g -fopenmp -O2  kmeans.h -c
```

Instead, what you probably want is something like...

```
%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CC_FLAGS) $< -c
```

Now the first prerequisite will always be the `.c` file but with an explicit dependency on the associated header.